# Correct using of CGI::Session, Perl

Tags: perl, session, authorization

I need to protect all pages on my site by login and password. I have one entry point, so it wouldn't be so hard. It is working now at the moment, but I want to improve authorization system (yes it works, but I want it would work correctly).

Code which check login and password is so:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{select count(*) from admin where login = '$input_login' and password = '$input_password_hash'});
$sth->execute();
($count) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
$sth->finish();
if ($count eq 1) 
{
    $session->param("user_logged_in", 'true');
    print '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/">';
}
```

2 questions about it:
1) Is it correct at all? 
2) Script behaviour for end-user is so: user writing his login and password, form is sending, login page is loading again and after this (redirect to login page with blank fields and showing it for 1 second) protected data is appearing. How to remove showing login blank form and just login immediately? Inputting login and password, sending form, and data is showing  immediately, not after showing blank login for 1 second. I think it is about meta redirect. What do you think?
It is first 2 question.

> When a user clicks another link or re-visits the site after a short while should we be creating a new session again? Absolutely not.

Quote from documentation of `CGI::Session` [CGI::Session Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/Tutorial.pm).

It says, that I should firstly check if user session is exist and if not, new session would be created. Code should be so:

```
$cgi = new CGI;
$sid = $cgi->cookie("CGISESSID") || undef;
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'../tmp'});
```

But for me this code is working fine too (I can get access to session variables):

```
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>'../tmp'});
```

3) Can you explain me why this code works? First code works too. But 2nd code (without $sid as 2nd parameter) have not to work (but it works).

Quesiton about accessing data from session:

```
$authorised = $session->param("user_logged_in");
```

4) Is it correct to access session variables this way? 
5) What if I need access to `$session` on other script? How should I get access to `$session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**

For starters, you have an SQL Injection vulnerability:

Change this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
   select count(*) from admin 
   where login = '$input_login' and password = '$input_password_hash';
});
$sth->execute();
```

to this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
   select count(*) from admin 
   where login = ? and password = ?;
});
$sth->execute($input_login, $input_password_hash);
```

**(2)**

Instead of doing a client-side (META-EQUIV) redirect from HTML, do a client-side redirect (HTTP) initiated by the server.

Change:

```
print '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/">';
```

To:

```
print $cgi->header('Redirect: /');
```

**(3)**

I haven't recently used CGI::Session directly like that, but I'd guess that it's designed to call  `new CGI()` for you in the default case.

I wouldn't do it that way; I'd call `new CGI()` directly.
**edit:** example:

```
my $sparams = { name => 'MY_APP' };
my $cgi     = CGI::Simple->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new(undef, $cgi, {}, $sparams);

# use $cgi for GET/POST params
# use $session for header & session storage.

print $session->header;
my $sval = $session->param('some-session-var');
my $opt1 = $cgi->param('some-get-var');
```

**(4)**

Yes, that's OK.

**(5)**

Then instantiate the session in those other scripts. You need to match the cookie `name`, `path` and storage method (using defaults will achieve that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Going to try this tomorrow. Question about 2. Will `$cgi->header('Redirect:/');` cause error `headers were already sent`?  `Content-type: text/html\n\n` is printed yet.

Comment: Yes, it will say that if you've already sent the `Content-type:` header. So don't do that! :-) Wait until you know whether your going to do one thing or the other before sending the `Content-type:` header.

Comment: What did you mean in (3) answer? You call `new CGI()` directly? What does it mean? How? Can you give an example please. My example is working , but I don't know why :( My code have not to work. `$session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>'../tmp'});` Also about (5) answer: I should initialise session same way?

Comment: What you're doing isn't wrong. I just usually separate the two constructor calls to make it a bit more understandable. (I've edited by answer to give a 'default' example).

Comment: Can you explain 3 first rows of this code? and also `print $session->header;`? What is the difference with mine? I set cookie by js, so browser know about session. Is it ok?

Comment: The first line is just configuration data for the 3rd line (telling CGI::Session to use 'MY_APP' internally to differentiate my code from others that might be setting cookies). The second line creates the CGI::Simple object that can be used later for getting request information. The 3rd line creates a CGI::Session object using that CGI::Session object. You need use the `header()` method of the CGI::Simple object, or your client-requests won't be associated with the same server-side session data on subsequent requests (it sends 'Set-Cookie` and `Content-type` headers amongst other things.